# SQL If statement for specific user

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have 2 users, one called admin, the other one called admin2.

I have wrote a SQL query in which I want to increase an achievement of a specific account, in my case only for `admin`, but inspite of that, the same achievement for user `admin2` is also affected. What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @Achievement1 INT

SELECT @Achievement1 = Achievement1
FROM [dbo].[Achievement]
WHERE [dbo].[Achievement].UserID = (SELECT [AccountID]
                                    FROM [dbo].[Account]
                                    WHERE [Username] = 'Admin')

IF (@Achievement1 < 100)
    UPDATE [dbo].[Achievement]
    SET [Achievement1] += 2
ELSE
    UPDATE [dbo].[Achievement]
    SET [Achievement1] += 0
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't appear to have any influence on the user 'admin2'. What other code do you have that involves 'admin2'? My guess is that 'admin2' is referencing the value of [dbo].[Achievement].Achievement1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is updating *all rows* in `Achievement` when the condition is met.  It is not just updating the matching row.

Your logic is rather convoluted.  I think you can just do this:

```
UPDATE a
    SET Achievement1 += 2
    FROM dbo.Achievement a
    WHERE a.Achievement1 < 100 AND
          a.UserId = (SELECT ac.AccountId
                      FROM dbo.Account ac
                      WHERE ac.UserName = 'admin' 
                     );
```

Note:  Having `UserId` in one table match `AccountId` in another is quite confusing.  Are you sure the comparison should not be either user ids or account ids?

Comment: Thank you, this was the easiest solution and it worked like a charm!

Comment: On the note, I've been a bit lazy to fix that issue, but i'll adress it also, so that problem will be out of the world.

Answer (score 2):

No need for all of this, you can just update with join like this:

```
UPDATE a1
SET a1.[Achievement1] = CASE WHEN a1.Achievement1 < 100 THEN a1.[Achievement1] + 2  
                          ELSE a1.[Achievement1] END
FROM [dbo].[Achievement] AS a1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Account] AS a2 ON a1.UserID = a2.[AccountID]
WHERE a2.UserName = 'admin';
```